# Frog in Akaka / Loango Région Gabon

Tags: species-identification, species

I was recently in Gabon, and I did some long and serious treks with Pygmées into some forest mostly to see Chimps and Gorilla around the Akaka area in Loango national park.
During a trek in forest I took a picture of this frog, it's been a little while now I can't find the exact species of it.

Any ideas guys ?

[image: Frog]

https://ibb.co/eU4ROk Full sized picture here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure as it's very difficult to determine frog species with just one picture taken from the side.
Morphology-wise it looks like this is a Afrixalis dorsalis, although it's colour doesn't comply with the most comomon pattern. You can find pictures of this species with specimen looking exactly the same or very similar.
Colour deviations occur in several frog species...

[interesting article about frog species in Gabon](http://www.zobodat.at/pdf/HER_19_3_4_0135-0148.pdf)
[AmphibiaWeb Afrixalis dorsalis](http://amphibiaweb.org/cgi/amphib_query?where-genus=Afrixalus&where-species=dorsalis) (this also mentions differences in patterns and light coloured populations)
[image: 3]
Source: Wikimedia Commons

[image]
Source: http://calphotos.berkeley.edu

[image]
Common colours and pattern
Source: http://calphotos.berkeley.edu

Comment: Thanks for your answer, true the morphology looks like afrixalis dorsalis, might be it ! Just could not find that pattern with the black strip from the eyes to the nose and also that little shiny yellow on the top of the eye. Could be a variation.